# How can I install the 64bit version of MS Office 2010 Trial?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, microsoft-office-2010

There are usually 2 problems that lead you to looking for a 64bit version of Office:

1. I downloaded the [free trial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/try-office-2010-FX101868838.aspx?WT%2Emc_id=ODC_ENUS_OATProdHome_MonTry&culture=en-us) of Office 2010, but it seems to be 32bit only.

   There is no other download link on the web site, but I'm sure there is a 64bit version as well and I want to use it. How do I get it?
2. Alternatively, you might be facing issues with installing your trial of Microsoft Office 2010 when having 32bit Office application already installed. You might be presented with an error such as:

   [image]

Comment: Why do you need the 64 bit version?  Microsoft and others recommend using the 32 bit version unless you are using VERY large files that could push the 4 GB RAM limit of 32 bit applications.  Many 32 bit plugins won't work on Office 64 bit so installing it is really not recommended unless you have a SPECIFIC NEED.

Comment: @MultiverseIT: This question is an [effort to address a specific issue I solved myself](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). The reason for the 64bit requirement is not relevant to the issue.

Comment: Maybe not, but why is educating others and providing a context a bad thing? I won't trouble you any more on this, but I find it selfish and unhelpful to others when you dismiss a VALID point because you believe it doesn't apply to you and couldn't possibly inform others.  I try to help others follow best practices and understand options. Best of luck to you.

Comment: @MultiverseIT: It isn't a bad thing at all, but you asked me why I need the 64bit version and I replied to that. Your point is definitely valid and I'm sorry if my statement sounded like I was dismissing it. In this question/answer I wanted to provide a solution to retrieving the x64 version of Office, detached from the decision whether it is the right version to use. If you feel that I'm still misunderstanding you, feel free to drop by the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: @MultiverseIT Just FYI: http://i.imgur.com/WnoyC.png Just noticed this in the latest installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original suggestion comes from [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/download-link-for-office-2010-64-bit-trial/7d0795a5-8626-41e4-b38a-6d827a32e480).

1. When you download a trial version of Microsoft Office, you should receive an email from Microsoft. Please note the highlighted link in the email. Follow it.

   [image]
2. Now, open your account:

   [image]
3. You'll now be able to download Office:

   [image]
4. Select **Advanced Options**:

   [image]
5. You'll now be able to download the 64bit version:

   [image]